Triangle not showing despite imgui and compute draw working fine
I am following vkguide but not exactly. I am struggling getting a triangle to appear. When looking at render doc, it seems the vertices are drawn correctly according the the mesh viewer, but nothing actually ends up being drawn?
I have checked my code against vkguide and everything seems okay, and I don't think I have missed anything.
I have also checked renderdoc to see if the shaders are actually a part of the pipeline, and it seems they are correctly, and each shader seems to be in the correct stage.
Vertex winding order: CCW
Cull mode: None
Triangle mesh in render doc:

Before drawing texture view:

After drawing texture view

Drawcmd pipeline state:

Vertex shader:
#pragma shader_stage(vertex)

struct VSOutput {
    float4 position: SV_POSITION;
    [[vk::location(0)]] float3 out_colour: COLOR0;
};

VSOutput main(uint VertexIndex : SV_VertexID)
{
  float3x3 positions = float3x3(
    float3(0, -0.5, 0.5),
    float3(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
    float3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
  );

  float3x3 colours = float3x3(
    float3(1, 0, 0),
    float3(0, 1, 0),
    float3(0, 0, 1)
  );

    VSOutput output;
    output.position = float4(positions[VertexIndex], 1.0);
    output.out_colour = colours[VertexIndex];
    return output;
}

Fragment Shader:
#pragma shader_stage(fragment)

struct FSInput {
    [[vk::location(0)]] float3 colour: COLOR0;
};

struct FSOutput {
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 colour: COLOR0;
};

FSOutput main(FSInput input)
{
  FSOutput output;
  output.colour = float4(input.colour , 1.0);
  return output;
}

Command buffer recording
void Engine2D::draw_geometry(vk::CommandBuffer command_buffer) {
    auto colour_attachment =
        init::attachment_info(swapchain.draw_image.image_view, nullptr,
                              vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal);
    auto render_info =
        init::rendering_info(swapchain.extent, &colour_attachment, nullptr);
    command_buffer.beginRendering(&render_info);
    command_buffer.bindPipeline(vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics,
                                triangle_pipeline.pipeline);

    auto view_port = vk::Viewport{}
                         .setX(0)
                         .setY(0)
                         .setWidth(swapchain.extent.width)
                         .setHeight(swapchain.extent.height)
                         .setMinDepth(0)
                         .setMaxDepth(1);
    command_buffer.setViewport(0, view_port);
    auto scissor = vk::Rect2D{}
                       .setOffset(vk::Offset2D{}.setX(0).setY(0))
                       .setExtent(swapchain.extent);
    command_buffer.setScissor(0, scissor);
    command_buffer.draw(3, 1, 0, 0);
    command_buffer.endRendering();
}

EDIT: I have tried using the same pipeline settings as vkguide, I checked everything over several times, and used and compiled the same OpenGL shaders as them just to be sure, it made no difference.
EDIT: I have tried changing the shader stage count to different values, this did not help

I managed to solve the issue. I switched to testing the program on my laptop, and a received a validation layer error on it that I did not on my other computer, which hinted at a colour attachment format being undefined. With this information I eventually figured out that I did not add the render attachment info to pNext.
auto pipeline_info = vk::GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo{}
                         ..
                         .setPNext(&rendering_create_info);

